# Enviar email com assinatura usando uma imagem

Tags: php, html

Olá! Eu tenho uma função num arquivo de um site em wordpress que dispara um email de confirmação quando uma pessoa preenche um formulario. Porém eu gostaria de colocar uma imagem como assinatura desse email. mas quando incluo um html img ele da conflito e da pau no site. Como eu poderia incluir essa imagem nesse arquivo php?

Segue a função da mensagem..

```
/* ==== E-mail Cliente ============================= */
/* Assunto que será exibido no e-mail enviado para o cliente */
$assuntoCliente = "Registro de Interesse em Curso";
/* Mensagem que será exibida para o cliente no e-mail enviado, no formato HTML     */
$mensagemCliente = "<html><body>Olá! <p>Agradecemos seu interesse em estudar          na Sustentare. Recebemos a sua inscrição.<p>Enviaremos em breve as informações necessárias para a efetivação de sua matrícula.<p>Consulte o programa de todos os cursos clicando aqui.. http://www.sustentare.net/site/my-mba/<p>Caso tenha alguma dúvida estou à disposição. <p><span style='font-weight: bold; color: #0e3178;'>Renata Giongo Rigato</span><br> renata.giongo@gmail.com <br> <br> site.com.br</body></html>";
```

Comment: a imagem pode ser adicionada no html e hospedada no site da empresa, facilitando seu desenvolvimento

Comment: Fiz isso mas da pau no site. Erro nessa linha que altero.. um erro de "php"

Comment: O erro pode ser por causa da forma como a função está dentro do WordPress. Pode colocar o código que você está usando e o erro?

Comment: Olá ricardo. Estou usando esse código <img src="ass-renata.png">  antes da "</body>" Do codigo que eu postei.

E o erro que da no site é esse..

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/storage/2/40/86/inpg/public_html/site/wp-content/themes/sus/functions.php on line 1091

Comment: tente fazer um escape das suas tags e caracteres especiais.

Comment: faz assim <img src=\"ass-renata.png\"> que resolve @Maicon

Comment: Po legal, não da mais pau no site @Otto . Mas no email recebido ele não mostra a imagem, fica um simbolozinho de imagem não encontrada.. sendo que ela esta no mesmo diretorio que o arquivo. tem ideia do pq??

Obrigado!

Comment: sim voce precisa colocar a url completa da imagem @Maicon

Comment: Bah, Esse @Otto é fera demais! Obrigadão cara.. resolvido!!

Comment: @Maicon coloquei como resposta marque como resolvido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagem pode ser adicionada no html e hospedada no site da empresa, facilitando seu desenvolvimento

assim `<img src=\"ass-renata.png\">`

você precisa colocar a url completa da imagem

Comment: Não seo o porquê, mas o nome da imagem me lembrou [uma questão deletada do meta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2532)...